# Why my programs is taking longer to execute with more threads allocated?

Tags: c++, multithreading, bash, c++11, go

I wrote two programs that computes area of a function with a certain number of rectangles using Riemann sums, one is written in Go and the other with C++.

The objective was to measure execution time and see which language is the faster on multithreading.

I ran the program on a 32-cores server (Dual Intel Xeon) using a bash script4 to run it with 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 and 32 threads. The script use `time --format %U` to get the execution time .

But as you can see in the results running the Go version using 1 core is 1.19 seconds and with 32 cores it's 1.69 seconds ! I thought using more cores would have made computations faster...

Did I made an error writing my programs ? Is the measure of time accurate ? Or maybe the results are good but how ?

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Sources :

Go code  : https://github.com/Mistermatt007/Benchmark-go-vs-cpp/blob/master/CalculGo/Calcul.go

C++ code : https://github.com/Mistermatt007/Benchmark-go-vs-cpp/blob/master/CalculCpp/Calcul.cpp

launch script : https://github.com/Mistermatt007/Benchmark-go-vs-cpp/blob/master/script/Launch.sh

Riemann sums  : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html

first results : https://github.com/Mistermatt007/Benchmark-go-vs-cpp/blob/master/results/GoVSCpp.txt

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16964563/why-is-multithreaded-slower

Comment: Depends on your code. Just because you use multiple thread it doesn't mean you will get faster code. Actually bad multithreaded code can easily be slower than the single threaded version.
This is a hard territory. :)

Comment: @Jerome I already removed all the print-things to get faster

Comment: @Melkon the code is dividing the range given in command-line args to all the threads, only some addition and multiplications are threaded (:

Comment: @Mistermatt: But it's matter alot how much times threads have to wait for each other, how much times CPU caches invalidating etc. These overheads can become huge. Also C++11 have a different memory model to support multithreading, so if you use an old compiler you can have serious issues because of it also. If you can show your code i suggest you to do it, so someone may can help you. :)
(I don't know much about GO and i also doesn't have wide knowledge about multithreading.)

Comment: @Mistermatt create thread take time too, same for wakeup a core.

Comment: @Melkon I'm using the latest version of g++ to compile, with -std=c++0x -pthread flags

Comment: @Mistermatt Ok, so you doesn't suffer because of the old memory model, but there still can be alot of problem. Writing good multithreaded code is really hard, i don't know if you can achieve correct measurement between the languages without wider knowledge. :/
Without the actual code it's hard to help you.

Comment: @Melkon Links was already included but my bad, it was not well formatted

Comment: @Mistermatt, sry, didn't notice it. At first sight the C++ code is fine, did el.pescado's answer was the problem?

Comment: The server is actually running the script with higher number of rectangles but it seems it was the time format !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to `man time`:

> U      Total number of CPU-seconds that the process used directly (in user mode), in seconds.

You are measuring CPU-seconds, i.e. time spent by each CPU cumulatively, not "wallclock" seconds. This measure won't go down with additional threads, because it is proportional to amount of work which is constant. On the other hand, this may go up with number of threads, as every new thread incurs some additional bookkeeping.

If you want to list "real" time, use `%e` specifier.

Comment: I had divided the output provided by the %U by the number of cores used and now with the %e it gives me larger times than before